# How to construct RDF using Data Cube Vocabulary with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, turtle-rdf, data-cube

I have CSV data set and I want to construct RDF using Data Cube Vocabulary.

Now I have triplifier, which constructs "regular" RDF with tarql:

```
PREFIX data1: <http://data1/#>
PREFIX data2: <http://data2/#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?URI a data1:Data1;
    variale:name ?name;
    variable:something ?something;
}

  FROM <file:data2.csv>

  WHERE {
    BIND (URI(CONCAT('http://data1/', ?someValue)) AS ?URI)
    BIND (STRLANG(?someName, "en")  AS ?name) 
    BIND (xsd:string(?anotherValue) AS ?value)
  }

OFFSET 1
```

I can find some explanations about how result RDF with Data Cube should look like, but I've found no examples about constructing it.

[Here is the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/worldbank/world-development-indicators/data) I'm trying to process.

Comment: My guess would be that you want to use some tool convert RDF into Data Cube Vocabulary. A number of [implementations](https://www.w3.org/2011/gld/wiki/Data_Cube_Implementations) exist, but they all seem to not be well maintained (with the last commit being 4+ years ago).

Comment: Please also paste sample CSV data...

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse the problem is I have to do it without tools, using only SPARQL.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I've put link to `CSV` in the description.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no open source tools exist that will let you read a CSV directly. Can't you use a script instead to read the CSV, put it into a graph, and then do the CONSTRUCT or INSERT? If you data isn't very large, RDFLib in Python is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL can produce tabular data from RDF data using `SELECT` queries, or RDF data from RDF data using `CONSTRUCT` queries, but SPARQL is not suitable for converting CSV tabular data into RDF.